# How does Node.js handle connections?

Tags: node.js, http, asynchronous, socket.io, serverside-javascript

I'd like to know how does Node handle connections. I mean: when I run...

```
node myserver.js
```

... and I make a request, what does Node do?

I've made a test. I have a server running with socket.io. I open two tabs in my browser which stablishes WebSockets connections. I check the threads (**ps -eLf**) and I get always the same 6 threads running:

```
node     12837 12518 12837  1    6 22:29 pts/0    00:01:10 node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-dev/wrapper.js prueba1.js
node     12837 12518 12838  0    6 22:29 pts/0    00:00:00 node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-dev/wrapper.js prueba1.js
node     12837 12518 12839  0    6 22:29 pts/0    00:00:14 node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-dev/wrapper.js prueba1.js
node     12837 12518 12840  0    6 22:29 pts/0    00:00:14 node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-dev/wrapper.js prueba1.js
node     12837 12518 12841  0    6 22:29 pts/0    00:00:14 node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-dev/wrapper.js prueba1.js
node     12837 12518 12842  0    6 22:29 pts/0    00:00:14 node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-dev/wrapper.js prueba1.js
```

I'm asking this because I'm trying to understand **what does the blocking code actually blocks**.

Comment: What "blocking code" are you talking about?

Comment: "Non blocking" and "multithreaded" do not mean the same thing.

Comment: Are you asking how `cluster` gives out connections?

Comment: With blocking code I mean synchronous functions. And what I really want to know is: does blocking code block the server for everyone that is connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to understand how asynchronous IO in node works on low level I suggest to read following documentation:

- [libuv book](http://nikhilm.github.com/uvbook/introduction.html)
- epoll ( [tutorial](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/BrainDump/Linux-Files-and-the-Event-Poll-Interface/), [manpage](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/epoll.4.html), [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoll))
- kqueue ( [manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/kqueue.2.html), [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kqueue) )
- [I/O Completion Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. I found more in [the Node's about page](http://nodejs.org/about/). I've not become a computing engineer, but I think I've an answer:

_Furthermore, users of Node are free from worries of dead-locking the process—there are no locks. Almost no function in Node directly performs I/O, so the process never blocks._

So, my conclusion is: I don't have to worry about the blocks between connections and I've to use `cluster` module for an high scalability.